# Valuation ring satisfying either a.c.c. or d.c.c. on prime ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, valuation-theory, krull-dimension

If a commutative ring with unity has finite Krull dimension, then it satisfies a.c.c. and d.c.c. on prime ideals. The converse is not true in general, as can be seen from here [An infinite dimensional local domain whose chains of primes are finite](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311907/an-infinite-dimensional-local-domain-whose-chains-of-primes-are-finite)

But, if $R$ is a Valuation ring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring) and satisfies both a.c.c. and d.c.c. on prime ideals, then $R$ has only finitely many prime ideals due to the comparability of any two ideals in a Valuation ring. So then it is natural to ask, what happens if we assume only of the chain conditions on prime ideals for a Valuation ring ...

Let $R$ be a Valuation ring  .

1) If $R$ satisfies a.c.c. on prime ideals, then does $R$ have finite Krull dimension ?

2)  If $R$ satisfies d.c.c. on prime ideals, then does $R$ have finite Krull dimension ?

By the remarks preceding the question it is enough to show whether any of the a.c.c. or d.c.c. on prime ideals imply the other ... but I don't see whether this is true or not ...

Comment: Since there are valuation rings having any given ordered abelian group as value group, it suffices to construct such a group whose set of convex subgroups is infinite but satisfies a.c.c. (resp. d.c.c.). That shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any totally ordered set $W, R=k[x_i/x_j^n: i,j \in W, i \lt j, n \ge 0]$ is a valuation ring with value group $\oplus_{i \in W} \mathbb{Z}$ and Spec($R$) = {initial segments of $W$}. Thus $W$=negative integers gives a counterexample to (1) and $W$=positive integers gives a counterexample to (2).;