# commutative ring satisfying descending chain condition on radical ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-rings, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity which satisfies d.c.c. on radical ideals. then does $R$ satisfy a.c.c. on radical ideals ? If this is not true in general, then what happens if we also assume $R$ is a local domain and/or that $R$ has finite Krull dimension ?

NOTE: If $R$ has finite Krull dimension, then obviously $R$ satisfies a.c.c. on prime ideals.

By the answer below of David Lampert, it follows that only assuming local domain is not enough to guarantee a.c.c. on radical ideals.

Answer (score 2):

Answer (2) here [Valuation ring satisfying either a.c.c. or d.c.c. on prime ideals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312106/valuation-ring-satisfying-either-a-c-c-or-d-c-c-on-prime-ideals/312109#312109) gives a counterexample to the first 2 questions (a radical ideal in a valuation ring is prime).

Comment: yes because a radical ideal in a valuation ring is prime